# How do I create randomized lists using a nested for loop

Tags: list, for-loop, random, nested-loops, probability

So I'm trying to make 2 lists with random variables compare to each other to find the probability of them being the same. What I've done is made 2 lists with random numbers using a for loop, but in order to find the probability I'm trying to create the lists within another for loop in order to make 10000 pairs of lists to compare but I can't get it to work.

```
import random
import collections

N= 10000
count = 0
playerPick=[]
randomPick=[]


for j in range (N):
    for i in range(4):
        playerPick.append(random.randrange(1,21))
    print(playerPick)

    for i in range(4):
        randomPick.append(random.randrange(1,21))
    print(randomPick)

    if collections.Counter(playerPick) == collections.Counter(randomPick):
        count+=1

    probability = count/N

    print("Probability of winning: ", probability)
```

The lists end up being super long but I just want them to be 4 long.

Comment: Have you [asked a rubber duck](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)? Stepping through the code in the debugger you get to where you reset the lists and ...?

Comment: 10000*4 = 40000 values will be appended to the list. How many times do u wanna repeat this loop?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a more efficient way to calculate the average match count.

```
import random
import collections

N = 10000   # main list length
L = 4  # each element is list of 4 elements

def getpct():
    # create random list of lists
    playerPick=[[random.randrange(1,21) for x in range(L)] for n in range(N)]
    randomPick=[[random.randrange(1,21) for x in range(L)] for n in range(N)]
    
    # create match list, 1=match else 0
    matches = [1 if p==r else 0 for p,r in zip(playerPick,randomPick)]

    return sum(matches)/N  # percent matches

allpcts = [getpct() for r in range(1000)]  # run test 1000 times
avgpct = sum(allpcts)/1000   # average percent

print(f'Avg Pct: {avgpct}%')
```

Output

```
Avg Pct: 6.2000000000000025e-06%
```